# Trying to create something similar to the "make-list" function in Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to code a function that will let me input a list, and it will produce a list of lists. Each list in the product will contain i+1 duplicates of the what was in index i of the original list.
So something like (expand (list "a" "b" "c")) will give me (list (list "a") (list "b" "b") (list "c" "c" "c")).

I am using Racket Beginning Student with List Abbreviations, and I am not allowed to use the "make-list" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write helper function with new argument (*i = number of duplicates*) and use function [`make-list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._make-list%29%29) for repeating given element *i* times (or write your own version of `make-list`):

```
(define (my-make-list i elem)
  (if (<= i 0) '()
      (cons elem (my-make-list (- i 1) elem))))

(define (expand-help lst i)
  (if (null? lst) '()
      (cons (my-make-list i (car lst))
            (expand-help (cdr lst) (+ i 1)))))

(define (expand lst)
  (expand-help lst 1))
```

Example:

```
> (expand (list "a" "b" "c"))
(list (list "a") (list "b" "b") (list "c" "c" "c"))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've added this. I am not allowed to use the make-list function, I have to create something that does the same thing manually.

Comment: @MaAsh3435 Check the edit.